# Master template for airium

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using **airium** as a replacement for the default Django templates system. In the default Django system the concept of **master template** is used to give a common frame and look to all the pages of a site by abstracting away the code common to all pages. I believe the same notion of a "master html" providing a frame is also worth when using Airium, no? **Is there a way to use such a "master html" with Airium?** Is it a concept existing within Airium? How could this possibly work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airium is just HTML generator, does not manage any django specific information.

There is nothing like this in `airium` (as for september 2023). You would need to manage it as a separate code.
I noticed you started an [issue in airium project](https://gitlab.com/kamichal/airium/-/issues/6). Thank you. Let me take care of it there.